# What is google colab power level?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Just find out that Google Colab is showing power level sign in the top middle. What does that mean?[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpZjn.png)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458800/meaning-of-power-level-on-google-colab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of "Power Level" on google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458800/meaning-of-power-level-on-google-colab)

Answer (score 2):

It's an April Fools day joke. Google has one every year.

https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1112708634905964545