# Meaning of "Power Level" on google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

When I open a new notebook on Google Colab I see a "POWER LEVEL" indicator with a battery symbol at the top.
I can click it and choose three different power levels: low, medium and high.

[image: Google Colab snapshot with Power Level]

I don't remember ever seeing this before on Google Colab. I believe this is a new undocumented feature.

Does anybody know what is the effect of changing power levels?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Power level is an April fools joke feature that adds sparks and combos to cell editing --

https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1112708634905964545

[image]

It is enabled and disabled in the notebook settings accessed via the Tools -> Settings menu item.

[image]