# What does the (real) Power Level in Google Colab means?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Power Level in `Tools > Preferences > Miscellaneous`
There are Three mods

- No power
- Some Power
- Many Power(use with caution)

and a Corgi Mode checkbox

Could someone please explain what this means :)
[image: screenshot]

Comment: by adding (real), I meant today is Not April 1

Comment: Whatever you do, do not _ever_ use many power. You cannot contain all that power, It will destroy you from the inside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of "Power Level" on google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458800/meaning-of-power-level-on-google-colab)

Answer (score 4):

This is a dupe of [Meaning of "Power Level" on google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458800/meaning-of-power-level-on-google-colab)

The feature stayed around after April first.

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate instead of mentioning it in the answers.

Comment: I thought this was different, since it appeared at a different place than mentioned at the other question.

Answer (score 2):

The April 1 feature stays.....

[image: colab tweet]

*[Link to Twitter post](https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1112940825162395649)*